# ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework The Type Not Mapped

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to access a single table entity that i have in a .edmx file within my ASP.NET MVC Project. When running the project i am getting the following.

> The type 'MvcApplication1.Models.tbl_dppIT' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive, nested or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.

All i am trying to do is access a certain column from the entity.

I am trying to access this item by doing the following.

Production Model

```
public class ProductionDataModels : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<tbl_dppIT> DPPITTable1 { get; set; }

    public ProductionDataModels() : base("name=MessagingSystemEntities")
    {

    }
}
```

Controller that i am using to access the model

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Real Time Production";

        var test1 = productiondatamodels.DPPITTable1.ToString();


        return View(test1);
    }
```

I have tried a number of different ways of access the production model but still get the same error. Am i doing something obvious wrong?

Comment: Why you just dont use repository logic  with interface ?

Comment: Sorry i dont understand what you mean?

Comment: try an mvc4 sample project.  There is generate Controller with EF model tool. Then look at generated code. You may be mixing MVC model with EF model